# Multi-step form

Tags: javascript, html, webforms

i'm having a problem on how should i implement/build my form. here's the overview.

the first step of the form is to fill up the "Responsibility Center". however, the user can add multiple responsibility center. then the next step would be - each responsibility center added should have one or many "account codes". at the end of the form, before submitting it, all the data should be editable.

the result should be like this:

```
|**responsibility center**||**account codes**|  
|        center 1         || account code 1  |  
|                         || account code 2  |  
|        center 2         || account code 1  |
etc..
```

i just need some idea on how the form should be built/implemented.

**EDIT 1**

**This is what i've tried**

**1st step**
[image: 1st step - responsibility center]

**2nd step**
[image: 2nd step - account codes]

**result**
[image: result]

**EDIT 2**
i already know how to add multiple rows (like on the 2nd step) and i can implement that already on the first to the 1st step. so here are my questions:

1. how can i add account codes per responsibility center?
2. if what i've tried is not a practical way to implement it, then how should i do it?

Comment: Please show us what you've already tried..

Comment: You have multiple questions here. I suggest asking specific questions, otherwise you will receive very generalized answers.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I began writing this answer before you posted the pics of your app. The ideas are still relevant, but I would have tailored my example more to what you are doing. Sorry about that.

I would use jQuery and AJAX to get the job done. jQuery to handle insertion of new elements to the DOM, and for field validation; AJAX to verify that no account codes are duplicated between RCs, or what have you. Personally, I would also use AJAX to handle the form submission instead of using the more traditional `<form action= method=>` because it gives greater control over the process and doesn't whisk the user off to another page before I am ready. However, it is easiest to describe the `<form>` example, and you can first build that and then change it over to using AJAX if you want.

The example from here is assuming a blank slate (i.e. I had not seen your sample app before writing this):

First, in your jQuery/javascript, you need a counter to keep track of each RC added. This can be in the `<head>` tags of your HTML/PHP, or it can be stored in a separate file. If you click on my name and look at other AJAX answers I've given, you'll see many useful examples.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var ctr = 0;
    });
</script>
```

In your HTML, you need a DIV into which you will append each RC DIV. You also need a link/button/whatever for user to initiate creation of a new RC. This would be a brief form, even just [RC Title] and [Account Code] with a link/button/whatever to create another [Account Code] field and a [Done/Submit] button.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <form action="yourprocessorfile.php" method="POST" id="myform"></form>
</div>
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Add New RC" />
```

JAVASCRIPT/jQuery (again, inside the (document).ready() section above):

```
$('#mybutt').click(function() {
    ctr++;
    var str = 'RC TITLE:<br><input id="RC-"'+ctr+' class="RC" type="text"><br>ACCOUNT CODE<br><input id="AC-"'+ctr+' class="AC" type="text"><br>';
    $('#myform').append(str);
});
```

When user presses [Done], use jQuery again to check that each [Account Code] field has been completed.

```
$('#done').click(function() {
    $('.RC').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            alert('Please complete all fields');
            $(this).focus();
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('.AC').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            alert('Please complete all fields');
            $(this).focus();
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('#myform').submit();
});
```

---

Edit 2 / Question 1:

You can add new account codes linked to an RC by:

- You need to somehow assign a unique data element to the RC, such as an incrementing ID
- have a link for adding the new AC
- use jQuery to get the ID of the nearest RC element
- use `.split()` to split-off the numerical portion (assign to a var)
- use that number when creating your AC

  $('.add_AC').click(function() {  //Note I used a class, so you can have a link for each RC
      var num = $(this).parent().attr('id').split('-')[1];
      var str = '';
  });

In the above example:

==> Because I used a class, it will fire whenever ANY element with that class is clicked. Of course, when you create the button, you must add that class to the button def, as:

```
<input type="button" class="add_AC" value="Add Account Code" />
```

num ==> uses chained jQuery methods to, one-after-another, get the number portion of the RC's id.

$(this) ==> whichever [Add Account Code] button/link/whatever was clicked on.

.parent() ==> This may or may not be correct for your situation. This is the part where we traverse the DOM to find the RC element's ID code, which would look like this: `RC-3`.  You will need to experiment with:

.parent().parent()
.sibling()
.parent().sibling()
.closest()
.prev() or .next()

Play with these selectors, with Dev Tools window opened. It should only take a handful of minutes to find your RC element -- or ask another question and post your HTML.

.attr('id') ==> Obviously, returns the text of the ID, in our case `RC-3`

.split('-')[1] ==> Creates an array with `RC` on one side (zero), and `3` on the other (1)

Hopefully this all gives you some idea of where to begin...

Comment: i apologize first for not making it clear at the beginning. your answer gave me helpful hints. especially not using 'action= method=' attributes.

Comment: Thanks, if my answer is useful please upvote it (if you have 15+ rep), and if it is the best answer please mark it as such. Remember, you can ask as many questions as you want on this same issue, with each question focusing on a different part of your problem.